# Unity treating selected button as different from highlighted button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, navigation

I am using Unity's standard button behavior, with automatic navigation, plus my own script to allow me to press e to select the currently selected button, and it works perfectly on multiple menus in my game, except for one. It works if I manually click the button, but not if I try using navigation and the keypress to select it. Instead it shows one button as highlighted, but treats the other button as selected

Here is the code for selecting with a keypress:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == this.gameObject && Input.GetKeyDown(_key)){
            //print("button pressed by E");
            _button.onClick.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

This works in multiple places.

I use a script to set the event system selected game object to the first option in my UI. That code is here:

```
private IEnumerator SelectFirstChoice(int thisChoice)
    {
        //print("hello from line 177");
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(checkpointButtons[thisChoice].gameObject);
    }
```

This also works in multiple places, and I have also tried calling it in 3 different ways to veryify it isnt an issue where it is being called multiple times, and the issue occurs no matter how I call it.
Together, these have allowed me to use wasd an e to navigate through all the various menus and dialogue in my game. Except for one.

Here is how the UI in question appears in the scene:
[Normal UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRvdW.png)

when I press s to move from the first option to the second one:
[UI navigated as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbbjO.png)

Expected behavior:
pressing e selects the option to stay here and runs the associated function.
Actual behavior:
e does nothing because the system believes the first option is still the selected one, even though the second option is the highlighted one.
If I press w to highlight the first option again, pressing e performs the expected behavior. Clicking the button also works, so it isn't the button's function failing to execute.
If I alter my keypress code to this:

```
public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        highlightedChoice = this.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(highlightedChoice == this.gameObject && Input.GetKeyDown(_key)){
            //print("button pressed by E");
            _button.onClick.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Then it just selects the top button even while the bottom one is highlighted.

This is all I have going on with this button.
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sifUE.png)

How is it even possible that the navigation is highlighting the other button option, but not treating it as the selected button?

An Update: using code I have confirmed that the selected game object is changing with w and s, and at no other time. but I still can't pick any option other than the first one.